# Populating listview from sdcard images

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I would like to add images from my `sdcard` to my `listview`. Currently I can choose picture from my `sdcard` by the button click on my `UI`. The implementation to choose picture is this:

```
sendPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mybyte=null;

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);               
    }
});
```

The `onActivityResult` of this implementation is:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {

        currImageURI = data.getData();
        myvariable=getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
            try {
                mybyte=fileToByteArray(myvariable);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My aim is convert "mybyte", which is a `byte[]` variable, to an image and put the image on my `listview`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement your own Adapter and override getView() to do this. You will find many examples here and on Github

Comment: convert your byte[] to bitmap and set it to ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such an implimentation,transforming byte[] to Bitmap and store Bitmaps in your adapter source list, you will get an OutOfMemmory error. Will be better to store in your ArrayList not the Bitmap but the path to it, you get it from cursor after chosing bitmap from galery, and load the Bitmap in an AsyncTask in the getView method of your CustomAdapter.Google has a good example on how to do a fancy ListView with ImageViews [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)